# WinRT Listview Content becomes invisible after 2^21 pixels?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have a problem displaying a *large* dataset (around 27k elements). The problem is that after a certain point items would not display anymore but would still be be clickable. In fact, the items would display when scrolling but would disappear as soon as the scrolling stops. After some testing I found out it was stopping rendering after the 2^21 pixel. Complexity of the objects being rendered do not seem to affect this limit.

I have made a sample project to illustrate this:

In a blank windows store app, replace MainPage.xaml default grid with this one

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textblock" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="Button_Tapped"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="Button_Tapped_1"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="Button_Tapped_2"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="Button_Tapped_3"></Button>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" x:Name="simpleList1" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-8" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkGoldenrod" x:Name="simpleList2" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-8" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="250">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue" x:Name="complexList1" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-8" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="333">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SimpleItem.Index}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ShortMsg}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding RandomNumber}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="3" Background="Violet" x:Name="complexList2" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-8" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="500">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SimpleItem.Index}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ShortMsg}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding RandomNumber}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And in the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    /// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public class SimpleItem
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public SimpleItem(int index)
        {
            Index = index;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "I am a simple item with index " + Index;
        }
    }

    public class ComplexItem
    {
        static Random rand = new Random();
        public SimpleItem SimpleItem { get; set; }
        public string ShortMsg { get; set; }
        public double RandomNumber { get; set; }
        public ComplexItem(int index)
        {
            SimpleItem = new SimpleItem(index);
            ShortMsg = "My simple item has index " + SimpleItem.Index;
            RandomNumber = rand.NextDouble() * (double)SimpleItem.Index;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "I am a complex item with index " + SimpleItem.Index;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SimpleItem> listSI = new ObservableCollection<SimpleItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<ComplexItem> listCI = new ObservableCollection<ComplexItem>();


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        InitializeLists();
        simpleList1.ItemsSource = listSI;
        simpleList2.ItemsSource = listSI;
        complexList1.ItemsSource = listCI;
        complexList2.ItemsSource = listCI;
    }

    private void InitializeLists()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i)
        {
            listSI.Add(new SimpleItem(i));
            listCI.Add(new ComplexItem(i));
        }

    }

    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int target = (int)Math.Pow(2, 21);
        int heigthPerItem = 100;

        SimpleItem item = listSI[target / heigthPerItem];
        simpleList1.ScrollIntoView(item);

    }

    private void Button_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int target = (int)Math.Pow(2, 21);
        int heigthPerItem = 250;

        SimpleItem item = listSI[target / heigthPerItem];
        simpleList2.ScrollIntoView(item);
    }

    private void Button_Tapped_2(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int target = (int)Math.Pow(2, 21);
        int heigthPerItem = 333;

        ComplexItem item = listCI[target / heigthPerItem];
        complexList1.ScrollIntoView(item);
    }

    private void Button_Tapped_3(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int target = (int)Math.Pow(2, 21);
        int heigthPerItem = 500;

        ComplexItem item = listCI[target / heigthPerItem];
        complexList2.ScrollIntoView(item);
    }

    private void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            string text = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();
            textblock.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

This should be the result (with some info how to use it) : [ListViewBugInterface](http://imgur.com/LbKDxg1?)

This person had the same [problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e35cc26-719f-429c-9b7f-91cfa6a69be0/winrt-bug-report-listview-with-large-dataset-being-clipped?forum=winappswithcsharp) as me and says it fixed it by using a VirtualizingStackPanel, but this shouldn't be needed since windows 8.1.

I doubt it is a UI virtualization problem since the ListViews scroll smoothly, the items start appearing when scrolling and can be tapped/clicked.

Anyone had this behavior? Am I missing the obvious? (e.g: to not have a dataset of 27k items) Anyone knows a solution to make the items render after the 2^21 pixel?

TLDR:
When displaying pixels after 2^21 pixels of combined ListViewItem they stop being rendered but can still be clicked. How do I fix this?

Comment: I tried adding a VirtualizingStackPanel like the guy in the other thread, it does work but it is just a workaround for the moment. Using [ItemsStackPanel and ItemsWrapGrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alainza/archive/2014/09/04/listview-basics-and-virtualization-concepts.aspx) like we should do in windows 8.1 does not work. Why does it work? Because VirtualizingStackPanel virtualize the UI on groups and not on Items, in my case, VirtualizingStackPanel just break the UI virtualization and make all the items render.